# overwrite another tag in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to minimize the height between the words: "frihedskamp og fremtidsforelskelse"

If I delete the CSS tag in line 149, the height between the lines are normal. I tried to add the following to overwrite that on line 266:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <article class="block-thumbnail">
        <a href="#" class="block-thumb">
            <div class="block-image">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <img src="/images/courses/au/designteori-og-historie/forelaesninger-slides/frihedskamp-og-fremtidsforelskelse.jpg" alt="Designteori">
            </div>
        </a>

        <div class="block-data">
            <h3>
                <a href="#">Frihedskamp Og Fremtidsforelskelse</a>
            </h3>
        </div>
    </article>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.block-thumbnail .block-data h3 a {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.0
}
```

I thought that a line-height could do the job, but that is not working. Does anybody have an idea on how I can set a "normal" line-height?

Comment: try `.block-thumbnail .block-data h3 { font-size: 18px; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should put `px` after the line height. secondly you can put the `!important` after the line height like `line-height: 25px !important;`

I think the line-height by default is `25px` or `20px`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can see this is working if I delete the "a" in .block-thumbnail .block-data h3 a{ } . Cant I make it work without deleting the a?

Comment: No you know what, I actually gonna go with your solution, and then just make the picture to a link, and not both: https://vouzalis.com/courses/AU/designteori-og-historie.php#

Comment: You do not need a unit on line height (e.g. `px`). For reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 .block-thumbnail .block-data h3 a { 
       font-size: 18px !important; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The fontsize should still be 18px; , so it does not solve the problem with the line height.

Comment: Ok I also edit my code. So may be now it will solve your problem.

Comment: But to set the !important on the font size does not change the line height.

Comment: p.small { line-height: 90%;} or p.big {  line-height: 200%;} Please check this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_dim_line-height.asp